# Excel VBA to perform actions after the save button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to piece this together with my limited understand of VBA, but all of the dots do seem to line up.

I have two SharePoint environments.  One is for internal company use the other is for external access.

There is a workbook that gets updated in the internal environment constantly.  When that work book is saved I want to

1. Complete save action
2. Delete columns where headers equal "Red", "Blue" and "Green"
3. Save As "Newbook.xlsx" to external sharepoint (if file exists overwrite).
4. Keep original workbook open

It is imperative that the original copy of the book be saved intact as normal and a new copy of the book is saved less the specific columns.

I have tried using this bit of code added to the "This Workbook" section:

```
Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
If Success Then
Call module1.Save
End If
End Sub
```

Where Module 1 has been created and reads

```
Sub Save()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test 1")

End Sub
```

I get a loop where it just keeps saving over and over again that will not end.  I also attempted to use this bit in place of the save function (to test the delete rows)

```
dim a as long, w as long, vDELCOLs as variant, vCOLNDX as variant
vdelcols = array("Blue","Red","Green")
with thisworkbook
    for w=1 to .worksheets.count
        with worksheets(w)
            for a=lbound(vdelcols) to ubound(vdelcols)
                vcolndx=application.match(vdelcols(a), .rows(1), 0)
                if not iserror(vcolndx) then
                    .columns(vcolndx).entirecolumn.delete
                end if
            next a
        end with
    next w
end with
```

And while yes it did delete the columns I want deleted the save action on the original book did not complete.

I *think* I'm most of the way there, I just cant seem to bring it home.

Comment: You need to disable events as `Application.EnableEvents = False` before saving it as another workbook and enabling them right after. I think this is the reason you get into loop, as you get at the start of `Workbook_AfterSave` event again.